# BarChart Labels for two lists

Tags: labeling, charts

a quick question:

I am trying to label a BarChart that consists of two lists (groups). The label should keep going on with the Label list (so ddd, eee, fff) and not repeat itself (and start from aaa, bbb...) after the first group ends (see picture underneath)

A simplified code:

```
  BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff}, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green}, None}]
```

[image]

With the dataset:

[image]

Comment: try: ChartLabels -> {{aaa, bbb, ccc}, {ddd, eee, fff}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
labels = {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff};
labeleddata = TakeList[MapIndexed[Labeled[#, labels[[#2[[1]]]]] &, 
  Flatten @ data], Length /@ data]

BarChart[labeleddata, ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green}, None}]
```

[image]

You can also  define `labeleddata` as

```
labeleddata = MapThread[Labeled] /@ Transpose[{data, TakeList[labels, Length /@ data]}]
```

**Update:** An alternative approach using the option `LabelingFunction`:

```
ClearAll[labelingF]
labelingF[data_, labels_] := 
 Association[
  Flatten@MapIndexed[#2 -> # &, TakeList[labels, Length /@ data], {2}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
labels = {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg, hhh};

BarChart[data, ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green}, None}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Rotate[#, 60 Degree] &@labelingF[data, labels]@#2, Below] &)]
```

[image]

Use `data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}}` and `ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Orange}, None}` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it only takes the first two values of the list (I added a screenshot above), do you know why this is?

Comment: @FayeDrew, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!